# What is the label attribute used for in the Navigation component?

Tags: android

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#anatomy):

> The Label field contains the name of the destination’s XML layout
>   file.

Fair enough, but I can't seem to find a use for it. Why does the layout file need to be named?

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/blank"
    android:name="com.example.app.BlankFragment"
    android:label="Blank"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_blank"/>
```

Is the `label` attribute strictly for the internal workings of the Navigation framework, and not something I should worry about?

Comment: you are correct the design tab uses the id, I deleted my answer as it was indeed wrong. thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [Update UI components with NavigationUI documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#top_app_bar):

> `NavigationUI` contains methods that automatically update content in your top app bar as users navigate through your app. For example, **NavigationUI uses the destination labels from your navigation graph to keep the title of the top app bar up-to-date.**
>
> When using NavigationUI with the top app bar methods discussed below, the label you attach to destinations can be automatically populated from the arguments provided to the destination by using the format of {argName} in your label.

Just like any other information attached to each destination, it can also be used in a [custom `OnDestinationChangedListener`](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events) if you have other UI that needs to be updated with a label for the current destination.

Comment: Ah, ok. Good to know! That will come in handy. Thank you! I was looking at it from the perspective of an app that will get internationalized, so at design-time, it doesn't _really_ matter what the label is.. Also, the docs use snake_case in some places.. and that will probably never get shown to the user, so it just added to my confusion. Thanks for clarifying and good job on Navigation so far!

Comment: Yeah, you'd always want to use a string resource as your label, rather than a fixed string